# Cuales son todas las PROPIEDADES para editar el SCROLLBAR del Body?

Tags: css

**Busco una Guia de todas la propieadades que existen para poder editar el SCROLLBAR asi como Observan las imagenes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 115px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: yellow;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background:rgba(0,0,15,0.7);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: rgba(0,0,15,1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #666666;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: #666666;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
  background: #333333;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
body { SCROLLBAR-FACE-COLOR:red; SCROLLBAR-HIGHLIGHT-COLOR: brown; SCROLLBAR-SHADOW-COLOR: #6699CC; SCROLLBAR-3DLIGHT-COLOR: #FFFFFF; SCROLLBAR-ARROW-COLOR: #FFFFFF; SCROLLBAR-TRACK-COLOR: #E3E3E3; SCROLLBAR-DARKSHADOW-COLOR: #000000; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="col"> Un Col 1</div>
  <div class="col"> Un Col 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="grid-3_xs-3">
  <div class="col-3_xs-10"> Un Col 3</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-4"> Un Col 4</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-7"> Un Col 5</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-8" data-push-left="off-2"> Un Col 6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="grid-6">
  <div class="col"> Un Col 1</div>
  <div class="col"> Un Col 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="grid-3_xs-3">
  <div class="col-3_xs-10"> Un Col 3</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-4"> Un Col 4</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-7"> Un Col 5</div>
  <div class="col-3_xs-8" data-push-left="off-2"> Un Col 6</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con tu pregunta? se puede, solo hay que hacer cambios en el CSS

Comment: quiero hacer estilo en forma de bolita al SCROLLBAR-THUMB asi como se aprecia en la imagen. o si tienes una guia completa para darle estilo al <Scrollbar seria de gran ayuda

Comment: Edite el titulo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen diferentes atributos para poder modificar el scroll aqui listo algunos:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

[image: webkit-scrollbar]

puedes empezar por aqui:

> [W3school - Custom Scrollbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

aunque si lo que buscas es un plugin:

- [CUSTOM SCROLLBAR PLUGIN](http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-custom-scrollbar/full_screen_preview/16768065?_ga=2.146412087.2013789316.1515203971-344045450.1515203971)
- [Custom scrollbars](https://escss.blogspot.mx/2012/09/estilos-scroll-personalizado.html)
- [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) aqui el [(**ejemplo**)](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

Comment: Sabes o conoces una guia para hacer el efecto que aparece en los ejemplos donde desplazas el scrollbar y crea un desplazamiento suave porfa

Answer (score 0):

Con CSS no podrás hacerlo de forma que sea funcional para todos los principales navegadores.
Si bien es cierto que hay algunos navegadores, (como Chrome, IE´s, Opera...) que tienen cada uno su grupo de propiedades privativas para estilizar algunos elementos de ellas, otros como Firefox carecen por completo de ellas.

Vía CSS podrías cambiar su apariencia con ayuda de los modos de fusión CSS (en aquellos que le dan soporte) o hacer lo que hacen los scripts: esconder las barras y crear otros elementos y darles estilos.
Pero tiene sus limitaciones e inconsistencias.

Así que lo único "efectivo" es que recurras a javascript. Hay infinidad de librerías para ello.

Si quieres o necesitas ampliar algo de lo dicho en el siguiente artículo tienes más información:
https://escss.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/estilos-scroll-personalizado.html

Saludos